# How to set scroll position for long PreferenceScreen

Tags: android

Android app has some very long preference screens, which always open at the top of the preference menu.  I have some idea where the user wants to be in the preference menu.  How can I force the preference screen to open scrolled to a specific preference item?

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `scrollToPreference` :

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat#scrollToPreference(androidx.preference.Preference)

Example:

```
scrollToPreference(preferenceKey)
```

or:

```
scrollToPreference(preference)
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old one, so this answer is just for reference.

To auto-select a given screen, all you have to do is `setPreferenceScreen()` (this is for a pre-Honeycomb non-Fragment PreferenceActivity).

Once you're on the correct PreferenceScreen, you can indeed use `getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(position)` (but this is a Froyo+ method), or you can use `getListView.setSelection(position)`.

But how to get the position?

First, watch out for the trap: `PreferenceActivity.getListAdapter()` does not return the actual ListAdapter, but a local instance variable which is disconcertingly not in sync with `PreferenceActivity.getListView().getAdapter()` (and usually null).

Second, trying to use `Preference.getOrder()` returns the order of the Preference object within its parent, which is what you want to use for the position **only if you're not using `PreferenceCategories`** since what you need is its order within the PreferenceScreen.

If you are using PreferenceCategories, you need to iterate over the items in the adapter (`for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++)`until you find the right one, and use its position.

Another corner of the Android SDK that is in dire need of some attention…

Answer (score 3):

Add this function to your PreferenceFragment

```
public void scrollToItem(String preferenceName) {
        ListView listView = ButterKnife.findById(getView(),android.R.id.list);
        Preference preference = findPreference(preferenceName);
        if (preference != null && listView != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
                Preference iPref = (Preference) listView.getAdapter().getItem(i);
                if (iPref == preference) {
                    listView.setSelection(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Lets say you have settings.xml with this

```
<Preference
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_email"
    android:key="emailSupport"
    android:title="@string/email_support" />
```

You can call

```
scrollToItem("emailSupport");
```

*Note: You may need to replace `listView.setSelection(i)` with `listView.smoothScrollToPosition(i)`*

Comment: Your solution worked for me but I had to replace listView.setSelection(i); by listView.smoothScrollToPosition(i); to make it work. Note that I'm not using fragments in that app.

Answer (score 1):

Since PreferenceActivity extends ListActivity, you can call `getListView()` to get the ListView containing your preferences, and then use `listView.smoothScrollToPosition()` to scroll to a specific row in the list. I haven't actually tried this before, but it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a subscreen, not the main activity screen.  So the question now becomes, how can I get a view or activity associated with a PreferenceScreen.  I tried to subclass it and override the bind() method, but darn class is declared final and can't be subclassed :(

Any other bright ideas????

Comment: When you say subscreen, what do you mean? Is it a completely different PreferenceScreen, or is it a subview of the PreferenceScreen?

Comment: kencorbin, I'm in need of the very same thing! Were you able to find a solution?