# Is it possible to auto-scroll down a PreferenceFragment to a desired (settings) entry?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I'm using `startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class))` from an `Activity` to call the `PreferenceFragment` of my app when a certain user interaction is required to be performed into the preferences.
I think would be good to scroll down to reach the involved preference.

I found solutions about how to scroll views into `ScrollView`s and `ListView`s, but nothing related to `PreferenceFragment`s.

My preferences look like:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // ...

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings, false);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

        //preferences:
        private Preference p
        // [...]

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

            //preference click listeners...
            p = (Preference) findPreference("PR_NAME");
            p.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    // ...
                    return true;
                }
            });
            // [...]
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Hey stranger! thanks for the sudden UP click.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837257/how-to-set-scroll-position-for-long-preferencescreen/43055656#43055656

Comment: check out this https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html#scrollToPreference(androidx.preference.Preference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is possible but it is hacky so nor recommended. it assumes that Preferences are backed by a ListView with id ==  android.R.id.list, so when you have reference to that ListView you can call setSelection(position)

Comment: Thanks, more or less what I was thinking... can you give some more details? In the mean time I'll continue my research and post any update.

Comment: well, just use findViewById(android.R.id.list) and cast the result to ListView

Comment: `ListView lv = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);` for the Fragment OR without `getActivity()` into the Activity `OnCreate()`, returns **null**. So maybe it's not the right answer...

Comment: as i said its hacky, i tested it with PreferenceActivity and it worked ok

Comment: Indeed, simply changing `public class SettingsActivity extends Activity` to `public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity`, findViewById returns **not null**. Great. Now I have to find out why `lv.smoothScrollToPosition(9)` doesn't do anything.  ;)

Comment: hint: Log.d(lv.getAdapter()), do it in onCreate and say 500 ms later

Comment: Always null? Even after some time, even after you see your preferences on the. screen?

Comment: yes, I tried linking `ListView lv = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
              Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "adapter: " + lv.getAdapter());` to a checkbox click listener, so all the preferences were on the screen.

Comment: @ pskink, let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42649/discussion-between-dentex-and-pskink) Hope it's OK for you.

Answer (score 6):

To scroll in PreferenceScreen (Setting/Preferences), Use this for Android API 24.1.+ or with [androidX API](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html#scrollToPreference(androidx.preference.Preference))

```
public void scrollToPreference (String key)
```

Comment: for whatever reason, this doesn't seem to work if your Prefs are dynamically created.

Comment: @lasec0203 use this scrollToPreference(@NonNull Preference preference)